# Use still stuck around after Def is destroyed:

Tags: llvm

Why it is giving error

```
While deleting: i32 %
Use still stuck around after Def is destroyed:  %in = alloca [3000 x i32], align 4
opt: Value.cpp:79: virtual llvm::Value::~Value(): Assertion `use_empty() && "Uses remain 
when a value is destroyed!"' failed.
```

when I am running my LLVM Pass containing these lines
.
.
.

```
Type *t3=dyn_cast<Type>(ArrayType::get(Type::getInt32Ty(context),50));
AllocaInst *al2=new AllocaInst(t3,"ar",ins1);
```

.
.
.
Here I am trying to allocate a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your pass is doing more than emit an alloca?  Your error line above has a 3000 element array while the code snippet below generates a 50 element one.

Are you doing possibly an eraseFromParent() on the alloca instruction above?  An instruction cannot have any uses when it is being destroyed; You may want to look at replaceAllUsesWith() though I can't say much more without more information as to what your pass is doing.